# Erro ao conectar com banco DBC

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou tentando conectar meu programa em um banco DBC usando o tutorial desse link:

http://rodrigolameira.blogspot.com.br/2009/08/conectando-banco-dbc-em-c.html

O código usado é o seguinte:

```
string path = @"D:\tabwin\";
string cs = "Driver={Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver};SourceType=DBC;SourceDB=" + path + "PAPE1701.dbc;Exclusive=No; NULL=NO;Collate=Machine;BACKGROUNDFETCH=NO;DELETED=NO;";
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(cs);
conn.Open(); //<<< LINHA COM ERRO
string sql = @"SELECT * FROM pape1701";
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, conn);
OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
//dataGridView1.DataBind();
conn.Close();
```

Ao executar o programa, recebo o seguinte erro:

> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Nome da fonte de dados não encontrado e nenhum driver padrão especificado

Como corrigir?

Comment: Você já verificou se a fonte de dados `Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver` está instalada na sua máquina? Utilize o Administrador de Fonte de Dados ODBC do Windows para ver isso.

Comment: Desisti, decidi fazer o sistema no Delphi